# Errors bubbling up to Mocha test even with a try/catch block

Tags: json, node.js, mocha.js, bdd, assert

---

I'm facing an issue with Mocha at the moment that I cannot seem to figure out or determine a way around.

I have a function that I am testing:

```
function toJSON(json) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(json);
    } catch(err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I have this test:

```
describe('example test', () => {
    it('should return false with invalid json` () => {
        let result = toJSON('invalid json');

        assert.equal(result, false);
    });
});
```

I would expect that the test should pass since I have a try/catch block in the `toJSON` function and it returns `false`. The problem I'm seeing is that the thrown error from `JSON.parse` is bubbling up to Mocha and failing the test.

If I wrap the code in a try/catch inside the `it` function, it will pass, but since an error is thrown, the `assert` is never reached and I cannot put the `assert` into the catch block as result will be undefined (even with defining outside of the try/catch).

I've tried a few different combinations, but unable to test that the return value is actually `false` in this case.

Is there a way to handle this that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Please, provide a way to replicate the problem - a repo or so. There is no way how error can bubble up from this function. Whatever the problem is, it's something that stayed behind the scenes. A file being cached, wrong tree being checked out, etc.

Comment: I figured it out. I have an event being emitted called "error" and that is ultimately being caught by Mocha, although their documentation does not say so.